# Openshift Maven project fails to find java 8 compiler

Tags: maven, openshift

Does anyone know what is needed to force a Maven openshift (jbossews) project to build with a java 8 compiler instead of the java 7 one?

I want to upgrade my project from java 7, so I changed my POM to specify source/target 1.8 in the compiler plugin, 1.8.0 in the enforcer plugin and added a java8 .openshift/marker file to my project. But I see when the maven build starts up it still says

Java version: 1.7.0_85, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85/jre

..and the build fails with
remote: Detected JDK Version: 1.7.0-85 is not in the allowed range 1.8.0.

Answer (score 1):

I Had a very similar problem, and had to report an issue which had been fixed for a Wildfly 8 openshift cartridge, titled:
["Way to override JAVA_HOME hardcoded in /usr/bin/mvn script"](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1109980)

You should probably also report an issue for your cartridge.

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your environment variable `JAVA_HOME` to a JDK8 installation.

Comment: My JAVA_HOME points to /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0 (which is a link that resolves to /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.51-1.b16.el6_7.i386) - for some reason Maven doesnt pick that up

Comment: Ok, so where does `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.85` come from? I just upgraded to Java 8u65 and I only needed to update `JAVA_HOME` for Maven to pick it up. 

When you installed Maven, did you follow the official instructions at http://maven.apache.org/install.html ?

Comment: I didn't install maven myself, I just use the pre-installed one. Is it necessary for me to install my own to change java version?

Comment: It's probably not absolutely necessary, but it begs the question of how the pre-installed `mvn` is determining which Java to use. If you do a `which mvn` and take a peek inside the file, it might shed some light on the issue.

Comment: Ok so it seems mvn completely ignores the JAVA_HOME and goes to a hardwired location. Which seems rather restrictive. I think the only way is to install a fresh one.

Comment: You might be right. At least that'll put you in same boat as the rest of us... :-)

Answer (score 0):

I just switched my application from java7 to java8 successful. I am running a diy cartridge with spring boot but i faced the same problem you described.

My solution was described in that tutorial very well:
http://fabiomaffioletti.me/blog/2015/12/09/openshift-diy-java-8-spring-boot/

He described that he downloaded his own maven and java8. But since java8 is already available under /etc/alternatives/java_sdk_1.8.0 I took this one and only downloaded my own maven und used that one.

The problem with the preinstalled maven is that under /usr/bin/mvn the java7 is hard wired. So it is not enough to just set $JAVA_HOME to java8.